# Google maps - 200K + polygons on the map

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have to plot 200K+ polygons (building shapes) on google map in my project. I have already plotted them on the map. But when moving the map around, it takes sometimes to render polygons. Sometimes even browser tends to freeze. I am looking for either an alternative technique to do that(Something better than Google maps) or a better way to manage polygons.

These are the constraints that I have
** this polygon information is generated on the fly and cannot be pre-prepared.
** Any viewer should be able to see all the polygons(Buildings) in a "bird eye view", so I cant restrict them into a particular zoom level.

Comment: you alway need  to show all the 200k polygons at all zoom level? ...  what you see for low zoom level  ?

Answer (score 0):

You should use some form of server side rendering to generate overlay tiles. We do a similar thing to you with thousands of geospatial objects on a google map. We use the https://carto.com/ service but there are others available and I encourage you to do the research.

Carto stores your data in a postgres database, and then you can use cartodb.js to overlay your rendered data on a map of your choosing (leaflet, google). You can then access click/mouseover events via cartodb.js

https://carto.com/docs/carto-engine/carto-js

I should add that this is easiest for static datasets, but data manipulation on the fly is certainly possible via many of their APIs.